# Is the `MEM_RESERVE` flag of `VirtualAlloc()` really useful today?

Tags: c, winapi, memory, memory-management, virtual-memory

First of all, let me say that I very well know how `VirtualAlloc()` works and how virtual memory facilities of the modern operating systems, in general, work.

Said that, using the `MAP_RESERVE` flag of the `VirtualAlloc()` Windows API, *without* using also `MEM_COMMIT`, has some practical use today?

I mean, when I call `VirtualAlloc()` with `MEM_RESERVE|MEM_COMMMIT` I both reserve and commit pages, *but* I know that the operating system will really allocate pages only when I try to write into them.
This optimization happens on practically all the modern operating systems.

So, with this optimization in mind, if I call `VirtualAlloc()` with `MEM_RESERVE` and then I call it several times with `MEM_COMMIT` to commit pages, isn't the *same* result of calling `VirtualAlloc()` only once, specifying `MEM_RESERVE|MEM_COMMIT` ?

Since specifying only `MEM_RESERVE` will only reserve pages boundary addresses, without committing real pages, but then `MEM_RESERVE|MEM_COMMIT` will reserve+commit only pages I write to, isn't using `MEM_RESERVE` alone, a waste of time today?
With only *1* call to `VirtualAlloc()` with `MEM_RESERVE|MEM_COMMIT` I can basically obtain the same result of calling `VirtualAlloc()` 1 time with `MEM_RESERVE` and calling it several N times with `MEM_COMMIT`.

As a proof of what I am saying, I have noticed that the `MEM_RESERVE` facility doesn't exist at all in Unices/POSIX systems which use the `mmap(2)` syscall.
Also there you can "commit" a big chunk of pages calling `mmap(2)` once, and then the pages will be really allocated only when you write into them, all optimized by the operating system.

So, is using `MEM_RESERVE` alone just an old days thing useful only when memory pages were a precious resource, and so today is useless?
Or, using this flag alone (and then calling `VirtualAlloc()` N times with `MEM_COMMIT`) still has some practical use that I am missing?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/q/10494588/613130 The difference is in the handling of the swap file (if the response there is correct)

Comment: On a 32 bit system with limited address space I can see that `MEM_RESERVE` by itself would still be useful. On a 64 bit system there's probably not much point.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

When you commit memory, the memory manager doesn't immediately allocate real pages for you, but [it does count them towards the total number available.](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20091002-00/?p=16513)  The memory manager will never commit more pages than actually exist, and you are guaranteed that when you access a committed page, the memory is there.

`MEM_RESERVE`'s purpose is to allocate virtual memory addresses. You can reserve as much address space as you want, up to many terabytes on 64-bit systems, even if you don't have many terabytes of actual space.

By default, Linux doesn't limit allocations to the amount of actual space available. This "feature" is called *overcommit*. That means that on Linux there are no separate reserve and commit steps. If you want to reserve address space on Linux, [another question recommends `mmap`ping an area with no permissions.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15261527/how-can-i-reserve-virtual-memory-in-linux).

Comment: Yeah, as I've guessed it was related to the swap space,the Linux overcommit facility, etc. The answer in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10494588/benefits-of-reserving-vs-committingreserving-memory-using-virtualalloc-on-larg explains it very clearly. I knew that `MEM_RESERVE` basically only writes a new node in a tree structure, representing your reserved address ranges. Then when you commit, the OS will really face reality and realize if it can commit those pages, checking the memory, swap file etc. That's very interesting the method of `mmap(2)` and `PROT_NONE`+`MAP_NORESERVE` -- thanks.

Answer (score 3):

In addition to the previous answer here is a quote from [Microsoft docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/memory/reserving-and-committing-memory):

> As an alternative to dynamic allocation, the process can simply commit the entire region instead of only reserving it. **Both methods result in the same physical memory usage** because committed pages do not consume any physical storage until they are first accessed. The advantage of dynamic allocation is that it minimizes the total number of committed pages on the system. For very large allocations, **pre-committing an entire allocation can cause the system to run out of committable pages, resulting in virtual memory allocation failures.**